# UINavigationBar abnormally behaves

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have subclassed a UINavigation Controller. Wherever I need to present a view controller I simply set the view controller as root view controller of my subclassed Navigation Controller and present(this is mandatory in my case) this subclass navigation controller. Further view controllers are simply pushed into Subclassed Navigation Controller.
Moreover I have customized my UINavigator bar as well.
But in one of my view controller there is abnormal behavior in Navigation bar title. It animates abnormally.  [Here is the link to this phenomenon](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7hyravxav9iup3/upload.mov?dl=0)

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Master", bundle: nil)
    let vc :TFChatViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TFChatViewController") as! TFChatViewController
    let navController = TFPresentedNavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is how I setup my uiNavigation Bar Items

```
self.rightButton!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 24)
            UtilityFunctions .setViewBorder(self.rightButton!, withWidth: 5, andColor: UIColor.white)
            self.rightButton?.cornerRadius =  3.0
            self.rightButton!.setTitle(rightButtonType == .addfriends ? "ADD FRIENDS" : "", for: UIControlState())
            self.rightButton!.titleLabel!.font = UIConfiguration.getUIFONTAPPREGULAR(sizeFont: 14)
 self.rightButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.rightNavigationButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.rightButton?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.rightbtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton!)
        self.rightButton!.titleLabel!.font = UIConfiguration.getUIFONTBOLD(sizeFont: 14)

        let negativeSpacer: UIBarButtonItem? = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer?.width = ConstantDevices.IS_IOS_6 ? -6 : -8

        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([negativeSpacer!, rightbtnItem!], animated: false)
```

left button

```
self.leftButton = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.custom)
                   self.leftButton!.setTitle("", for: UIControlState())
        self.leftbtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.leftButton!)
        let negativeSpacer: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = ConstantDevices.IS_IOS_6 ? -6 : -16
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([negativeSpacer, self.leftbtnItem!], animated: false)
        self.leftButton?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.leftButton?.isHidden = false
```

Finally Title

```
self.navigationItem.title = title
```

Comment: can you describe how you setup your title?

Comment: I have edited questions and have added the code